# Stacking Images in Beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, minipage

So I have this *code* that places images side by side in a frame:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Sample}
   \begin{figure}[ht]
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{Label for a}
            \label{fig:a}
        \end{minipage}
        \hspace{0.5cm}
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{Label for b}
            \label{fig:b}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

How might one modify this to have the images stacked ***vertically*** instead of side by side?

Cheers.#

[image]